# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}} dx \quad (1)$$

---

The typical way to confront this kind of integrals are the conjugates i.e:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}} dx  = $$
$$ \int \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\right) dx = $$
$$\int \left(\frac{(\sqrt{1+x})^2-(\sqrt{1-x})^2}{(\sqrt{1+x})^2-(\sqrt{1-x})^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)dx = $$
$$\int 1*\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)dx $$

That's a dead end.

---

I also tried other conjugate approaches (only the numerator, only the denominator etc) with no better luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Try multiplying by $\frac{-\sqrt{1- x} - \sqrt{x+1}}{-\sqrt{1- x} - \sqrt{x+1}}$.

Comment: Another way: substitute $x=\cos 2\theta$ and remember your double angle formulae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by the conjugate is not a dead end.  I'm not sure why you multiplied by the conjugate of the numerator and denominator, you can easily evaluate this integral just by multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator:

$$I=\int \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\right) dx$$
$$I=\int \frac{{(1+x)}+(1-x)+2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2x} dx$$
$$I=\ln{|x|}+\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \; dx$$
Let $x=\sin{\theta}$ to evaluate the integral:
$$I=\ln{|x|}+\int \frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}} \; d\theta $$
$$I=\ln{|x|}+\int \csc{\theta} \; d\theta - \int \sin{\theta} \; d\theta$$
$$I=\ln{|x|}-\ln{\big | \csc{\theta}+\cot{\theta}\big |}+ \cos{\theta}+C$$
Substitute $\theta$ back for $x$:
$$I=2\ln{|x|}-\ln{\big | \sqrt{1-x^2}+1\big |} + \sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you might have missed $x = sin(\theta) \iff dx = cos(\theta) d\theta$

Comment: I don't think I forgot it. $\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}=\cos{\theta}$ not $\cos^2{\theta}$.  @Veriun

Comment: True, thanks for the answer!

Comment: As the edit by @Veriun suggests: this answer is missing a lot of absolute value signs. There is also an additional problem in that $$\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx \neq \ln(x)$$since $$\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln|x|\color{blue}{+C}$$

Comment: @Axion004 Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ty: There is a still a subtle issue. After you integrate $1/x$ you get $\ln|x|+C$. So, you need to carry over the integration constant directly after you complete the integration.

Comment: @Axion004 One constant plus another constant is just another new constant.  I don't show this throughout the steps but I'm sure OP understands it.  The final result is the same.

Comment: I agree but this would change the third step from $$I=\ln{|x|}+\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \; dx$$ to $$I=\ln{|x|}+\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \; dx+C$$ Technically, it would be incorrect to omit the constant in the intermediate steps (I'm not sure whether the OP understands this - as a TA, this is a very common mistake).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}=t.$

Thus, $$x=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},$$  $$dx=\frac{2t(t^2+1)-(t^2-1)2t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt=\frac{4tdt}{(t^2+1)^2}$$ and we need to calculate $$\int\frac{4t(t+1)}{(t-1)(t^2+1)^2}dt.$$
Now, easy to show that:
$$\int\frac{4t(t+1)}{(t-1)(t^2+1)^2}dt=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}+\ln\frac{(t-1)^2}{t^2+1}+C.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}} \,dx $$

Rationalize:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\times\frac{-\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{-\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}+1}{x}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\frac 1x$$

Therefore

$$I=\int\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\frac 1x\right)\,dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\,dx+\ln|x|+C_1$$

Now, integrate the second integral by parts:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}dx=\sqrt{1 - x^2}\left( -\frac{1}{x}\right) +  \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left( -\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$
$$=-\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x} -  \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
$$= -\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x} -  \arcsin(x) +C_2$$

Thus, letting $C=C_1+C_2$ gives
$$I=-\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x} -  \arcsin(x)+\ln|x|+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x$ with $\cos{2\theta}$.

The above integral will simplify to:

$-2\int \frac{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}{\cos\theta - \sin\theta} \sin{2\theta} \mathrm d\theta $.

Then you can use integration by parts.
Note that: $-\mathrm d(\cos\theta - \sin\theta) = (\cos\theta + \sin\theta) \mathrm d\theta$.